# Ao executar método PUT em aplicação Grails sistema insere novo registro ao invés de atualizar

Tags: java, restful, grails

Ao tentar executar o JSON abaixo via método PUT em uma aplicação Grails o sistema insere um novo registro.

**URLMappings.groovy**

```
class UrlMappings {

static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }

    "/"(controller:"main")
    "500"(view:'/error')

    "/api/Patrimonio"(controller:"Patrimonio"){
        action = [GET:"showJSON", POST:"saveJSON", PUT:"updateJSON"]
    }

    "/api/Patrimonio/$id"(controller:"Patrimonio"){
        action = [GET:"showJSON", PUT:"updateJSON"]
    }

    "/api/Departamento"(controller:"Departamento"){
        action = [GET:"showJSON", POST:"saveJSON"]
    }

    "/api/Departamento/$id"(controller:"Departamento"){
        action = [GET:"showJSON", PUT:"updateJSON"]
    }

    "/api/Local"(controller:"Local"){
        action = [GET:"showJSON"]
    }

    "/api/Responsavel"(controller:"Responsavel"){
        action = [GET:"showJSON"]
    }

}
}
```

**DepartamentoController.groovy**

```
package br.ufscar.dc.dsw

import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*

import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;

import grails.converters.JSON
import grails.transaction.Transactional

import org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.Restrict;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.criterion.LogicalExpression;
import org.hibernate.criterion.MatchMode;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured

import br.ufscar.dc.dsw.util.Constantes

@Secured(['ROLE_MEMBRO_COMISSAO', 'ROLE_SERVIDOR', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'])
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class DepartamentoController {

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]
    def registros

    def index() {
        params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : Constantes.MINIMO_PAGINACAO, Constantes.MAXIMO_PAGINACAO)
        registros = Departamento.createCriteria().list(params) {
            if (params.query) {
                if(params.tipo == "Sigla")
                    ilike("sigla", "%${params.query}%")
                else
                    ilike("nome", "%${params.query}%")
            }
        }
        respond registros, model:[departamentoInstanceTotal: registros.totalCount]
    }

    @Secured([
        'ROLE_MEMBRO_COMISSAO',
        'ROLE_SERVIDOR'
    ])
    def show(Departamento departamentoInstance) {
        respond departamentoInstance
    }

    @Secured('ROLE_MEMBRO_COMISSAO')
    def create() {
        respond new Departamento(params)
    }

    @Secured('ROLE_MEMBRO_COMISSAO')
    @Transactional
    def save(Departamento departamentoInstance) {
        if (departamentoInstance == null) {
            notFound()
            return
        }

        if (departamentoInstance.hasErrors()) {
            respond departamentoInstance.errors, view:'create'
            return
        }

        departamentoInstance.save flush:true

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [
                    message(code: 'departamento.label', default: 'Departamento'),
                    departamentoInstance.id
                ])
                redirect departamentoInstance
            }
            '*' {
                respond departamentoInstance, [status: CREATED]
            }
        }
    }

    @Secured('ROLE_MEMBRO_COMISSAO')
    def edit(Departamento departamentoInstance) {
        respond departamentoInstance
    }

    @Secured('ROLE_MEMBRO_COMISSAO')
    @Transactional
    def update(Departamento departamentoInstance) {
        if (departamentoInstance == null) {
            notFound()
            return
        }

        if (departamentoInstance.hasErrors()) {
            respond departamentoInstance.errors, view:'edit'
            return
        }

        departamentoInstance.save flush:true

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [
                    message(code: 'Departamento.label', default: 'Departamento'),
                    departamentoInstance.id
                ])
                redirect departamentoInstance
            }
            '*'{
                respond departamentoInstance, [status: OK]
            }
        }
    }

    @Secured('ROLE_MEMBRO_COMISSAO')
    @Transactional
    def delete(Departamento departamentoInstance) {

        if (departamentoInstance == null) {
            notFound()
            return
        }

        departamentoInstance.delete flush:true

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [
                    message(code: 'Departamento.label', default: 'Departamento'),
                    departamentoInstance.id
                ])
                redirect action:"index", method:"GET"
            }
            '*'{ render status: NO_CONTENT }
        }
    }

    protected void notFound() {
        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [
                    message(code: 'departamento.label', default: 'Departamento'),
                    params.id
                ])
                redirect action: "index", method: "GET"
            }
            '*'{ render status: NOT_FOUND }
        }
    }

    def exportar = {
        chain(controller:'jasper',action:'index',model:[data:registros],params:params)
    }

    @Secured([
        'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'
    ])
    def showJSON(Departamento patrimonioInstance) {
        if(params.id && Departamento.exists(params.id)){
            render Departamento.findById(params.id) as JSON
        }else{
            render Departamento.list() as JSON
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    @Secured([
        'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'
    ])
    def saveJSON() {
        if (request.JSON != null) {
            def jsonObject = request.JSON
            def departamento = new Departamento(jsonObject)
            save(departamento)
        }
        render status: OK
    }

    @Transactional
    @Secured([
        'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'
    ])
    def updateJSON() {
        if (request.JSON != null) {
            def jsonObject = request.JSON
            def departamento = new Departamento(jsonObject)
            update(departamento)
        }
    }
}
```

**JSON Enviado**

```
{"nome":"TESTE", "sigla":"TE"}
```

Enviei esse JSON via método PUT pelo endereço http://localhost:8080/Patrimonio/api/Departamento/6 só que ao invés de atualizar o registro de código 6 ele insere um novo registro.
Via debug da aplicação Grails vi que ele está chamando corretamente o método updateJSON, contudo não atualiza o registro...

Estou usando Grails 2.4.2

Comment: Ele está inserindo, pois dentro do updateJSON() você está criando um departamento e passando o mesmo para o update(). No update existe um save nesse objeto. Pelo o que entendi do seu problema, no updateJSON você deve recuperar um objeto Departamento existente e não criar um novo.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas o método update está correto. Quando chamo ele pela aplicação o registro é alterado normalmente, o problema esta quando chamo o método updateJSON. Pelo que vi ele está inserindo o registro porque eu não estava enviando o id. Fiz um novo json adicionando o atributo id, mas mesmo assim ele fica NULL ao criar o objeto através do json....

Comment: Exatamente @Thiago, quando você chama o update() da aplicação, você passa uma instancia de Departamento que já existe, você provavelmente usa um get ou um findBy para encontra-la no banco. O problema é que o updateJSON não entrega uma instância já existente para o update. Ele cria uma nova instância e passa para o update. O método save, por sua vez, vai inserir um registro. Tente colocar no updateJSON algo assim: def departamento = Departamento.get(jsonObject.id) onde jsonObject.id deve ser o id de um Departamento já existente.

Comment: hmm entendi. Eu fiz buscar o registro, contudo como faço para setar os valores atualizados do Json no objeto??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O registro está sendo inserido, pois dentro da action **updateJSON** uma nova instância de Departamento está sendo criada e passada como parâmetro para o método **update**. O método **update**, por sua vez, salva esta instância. Como ela não existe, então um novo registro é inserido no banco de dados.

Para resolver, é preciso obter a instância que se deseja atualizar no **updateJSON**, para isso, é necessário utilizar alguns dos métodos de pesquisa em banco de dados disponibilizado pelo Grails (get, findBy, hql, criteria). Abaixo, deixo um exemplo de como isso poderia ser feito usando o get:

```
def updateJSON() {
    if (request.JSON != null) {
        def jsonObject = request.JSON
        def departamento = Departamento.get(jsonObject.id)
        departamento.properties = jsonObject
        update(departamento)
    }
}
```

No código acima, uma instância está sendo obtida utilizando o método **get** passando como parâmetro o ID do Departamento. Feito isso, utliza-se uma maneira Groovy (*departamento.properties = jsonObject*) de atualizar os atributos de um objeto.

Note que para isso funcionar os campos no mapa jsonObject devem ter o mesmo nome dos atributos da classe Departamento.

Uma outra opção de atualizar os atributos é utilizar o método **bindData**, disponibilizado nos Controllers.

Veja uma exemplo:

```
def updateJSON() {
    if (request.JSON != null) {
        def jsonObject = request.JSON
        def departamento = Departamento.get(jsonObject.id)
        bindData(departamento, jsonObject)
        update(departamento)
    }
}
```

Documentação: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Controllers/bindData.html